# How to be get propertychange event from Uc1 to Uc2 on one Windows (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a problem with WPF binding. I have frmBill.xaml Window with two usercontrol like that:

```
        <materialDesign:TransitionerSlide OpeningEffect="{materialDesign:TransitionEffect SlideInFromRight}">
            <materialDesign:TransitionerSlide.BackwardWipe>
                <materialDesign:SlideWipe Direction="Right"/>
            </materialDesign:TransitionerSlide.BackwardWipe>
            <materialDesign:TransitionerSlide.ForwardWipe>
                <materialDesign:SlideWipe Direction="Left"/>
            </materialDesign:TransitionerSlide.ForwardWipe>
            <local:ucBill_Information/>
        </materialDesign:TransitionerSlide>
    </materialDesign:Transitioner>
</Grid>
```

And I have two ViewModel as ucDeclarationViewModel.cs and ucBill_ViewModel for this. And using Thread with claim based to bind data between this by using a button click event (I got it), but I can not bind data from VM to V (Using prism). I know my issue, but I dont know how to solve it :(. Please help me.

```
private ucBill_InformationViewModel _ucBlvm;
    public ucBill_InformationViewModel ucBIvm { get => _ucBlvm; set => _ucBlvm = value; }
    public ucBill_Information()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ucBIvm;
    }
```

Comment: A UserControl should never explicitly set its own DataContext. Instead it should operate on a view model instance passed by value inheritance of the DataContext property. Either directly or by exposing dependency propertes that are bound to properties of the view model.

Comment: @DuyKhương: Where do you instantiate the ucBill_InformationViewModel?